# mongo findOneAndUpdate creates duplicate record

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have seen one similar query raised , but no proper solutions found.

sometimes, I am seeing duplicates records created for same matching conditions. Appreciate your help on finding solutions.
MongoDB server version: 4.2.7
"mongoose": "^5.9.6"

```
function addModify() {
    Sales.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        shopId: shopId,
        SalesId: SalesId
    },
    {
        $set:
        {
            amount: amount
            lastUpdated: new Date
        }
    }
    , { upsert: true }, function (err, list) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error(' Sales-- error - ' + ' - ' + JSON.stringify(err));
            cb({ err: 'failed transcation log' });
        } else {
            cb(null, null);
        }
    });

}
```

NB: Question Updated with more information based on comment received.

1. upsert is true is intentional , because the same routine is executed for addition and modification ( for matching shopId and salesId)
2. Just to clarify. This is not an always scenario. for experiment, I ran this in a loop for 10000 times. I could see, some times it insert more than 1 record( I could see upto 4 or 5) and NOT 10000 records
3. This code is accessed from an API end point with app server( nodejs) hosted in one EC2 instance and mongo on another EC2 instance

Comment: when you say duplicate records, what field are they duplicated by ? the `_id` is duplicated as well ? ☉_☉

Comment: ofcource not _id. QUery expected to do ( for matching shopId and sales Id, it should update the exsting records and not add new one(upsert is true here because I need to use this same for add and modify

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `{ upsert: true }` property to `false` and that way if a document is not found, a new one will not be inserted.

Comment: no . that is not my use case. it is used for addition as well as modification( for same shopId and salesId). Bigger question is why mongo inserts multiple records for same matching condition. I have added a script to do this action 10000 times, I could see some times it insert more than one( I could see upto 4 records)